# css syntax to get only a element inside another element

Tags: html, css

I need to create a class that only applies to the holder-left inside the holder, and not to the one outside the holder.

```
    <div class="holder">
            <div class="holder-left">
            </div>
            <div class="holder-right">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="holder-left">
    </div>

    div.holder {
            margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            width: 1002px;
    }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
div.holder > .holder-left
```

Or a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

```
div.holder .holder-left
```

The child selector will match `.holder-left` elements that are direct children of `div.holder` elements. The descendant selector will match `.holder-left` elements that are descendants (they could be grandchildren, for example) of `div.holder` elements.

Comment: ow, nice, thank you. child selector is the best for me, because I intend just to make sure people don't use the class without the holder outside. I'm a c# coder building some html. Html programmers, in most cases, don't know how to make a clean and good code.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
div.holder .holder-left
{
}
```

Comment: you mean `div.holder .holder-left{}`